# Illegal string offset '_token' when insert in database type array Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

i have problem Illegal string offset '_token' when insert in database type array Laravel 5.2, when i insert data array then it meet error, i can't insert in database:

> ErrorException in PayController.php line 43: Illegal string offset
>   '_token'

cart.blade.php

```
<form autocomplete="on" action="{{ url('thanh-toan') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="item">Item</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
            <td class="price">Price</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <input name='post_id' value="PAY<?php $random_numbers = mt_rand(); echo $random_numbers; ?>" hidden>
    <tbody>

    @if(Session::has('name_product') != null)
      @foreach(Session::get('product') as $key => $cart)

        <tr data-item-id="561c0ad6e4b0ad946d8ad2ce" data-chosen-variant-sku="SQ5269982" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1461913843731_402">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $key }}" name="rowid" class="id_up"></input>

            <input type="hidden" name="session_cart" value="{{ $cart['id'] }}"></input>
            <td class="item">
                <div class="item-image"><img src="{{ URL::to('/upload/images')}}/{{$cart['picture']}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="picture[{{ $key }}]" value="{{ $cart['picture'] }}"></input>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="item-desc"><a href="{{ URL::to('san-pham')}}-{{$cart['id']}}-{{$cart['name']}}"> {{ $cart['name']}} </a>
                <input type="hidden" name="name_session[{{ $key }}]" value="{{ $cart['name'] }}"></input>
                <div class="variant-info"></div>
            </td>

            <td class="quantity">

                <input size="2" class="qty" name="qty[{{ $key }}]" value="{{ $cart['qty'] }}">
                <div class="cooldown hidden">•</div>
                <a class="update_cart" href="#">Cập Nhập</a>

            </td>

            <td class="price">
            <span class="sqs-money-native"> {{ $cart['price']}} </span>
            <input type="hidden" name="price[{{ $key }}]" value="{{ $cart['price'] }}"></input>
            </td>

            <td class="remove">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('xoa-san-pham')}}-{{ $key }} "><div class="remove-item">×</div>
            </td>

        </tr>
     @endforeach
       @endif

    @if(Session::has('name_product') == null)
    <p>Không có sản phẩm nào trong giỏ hàng cả</p>
    @endif
    </tbody>

</table>
```

CartController

```
 public function checkout(Request $request){
    $input= $request->all();

    $pay = new Pays;
    $bill= new detail_bills;

    $token= $request->input('_token');

    $id_buy= $request->input('post_id');
    $name_product= $request->input('name_session');
    $picture= $request->input('picture');
    $quantity= $request->input('qty');
    $price= $request->input('price');


    foreach($input as $key => $n ) 
    {

        $arrData = array(
                   "id_buy"       => $id_buy[$key],
                   "name_product" => $name_product[$key], 
                   "picture"      => $picture[$key], 
                   "price"        => $price->price[$key], 
                   "quantity"     => $quantity[$key]                      
        );

    }   

    DB::table('detail_bills')->insert( $arrData );

    $pay->id_buy= $request->input('post_id');
    $pay->email= $request->input('shippingEmail');
    $pay->phone= $request->input('phone');
    $pay->firtname= $request->input('shippingFirstName');
    $pay->lastname= $request->input('shippingLastName');
    $pay->address= $request->input('shippingAddress');
    $pay->zip= $request->input('shippingZip');
    $pay->paypal= $request->input('paypal');


    $pay->save();
    $bill->save();

    $request->session()->flush();
    return redirect('');
}
```

Comment: please post more of your code ...

Comment: @HasanTareque: i updated code ^^

Comment: are you saving it by jquery/ajax?

Comment: @HasanTareque: i just use ajax in update quantity of products ^^

Comment: why you need to save the token?

Comment: @HasanTareque: i just testing, i forget delete it when up on stackoverflow, sorry

Comment: remove $token= $request->input('_token'); as well - you don't need this

Comment: @HasanTareque: it still not working

Answer (score 0):

You might have no input attribute for token in your form

```
$token= $request->input('_token');
```

add

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"/>
```

in your form and try again.

ref: [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes)

Comment: in cart.blade.php, i have add `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` but it still not working

Comment: instead of $request->input() try $request->get()